# Fade a view in/out from top to bottom or viceversa without translating nor shrinking the view using Scale

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I'm trying to achieve an animation of fading a view from top to bottom or viceversa. The view should remaing its proportions and location while disappearing. For that reason I cannot use the translation or the scale (the scale will shrink the view.

Can anywone help me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [overridePendingTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int)) will help?

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity.class);
startActivity(newActivity);
this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.swipe_left_enter, R.anim.swipe_left_exit);
```

and the anim swipe can be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="100%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:duration="100"
        android:fillAfter="true"/>
</set>
```

This is a swipe example, but can be used as a fade anim also.

P.S. I forgot to mention that you should implement

```
class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
   @Override
   public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                            float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        // your code here
   }
 }
```

[onFling](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html#onFling(android.view.MotionEvent,%20android.view.MotionEvent,%20float,%20float))

Comment: The animation should be applied to a view, sorry if I didn't specified that.